# Invalid cookie header: "set-cookie: sid="";Version=1;Path=/;Max-Age=0;Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"

Tags: apache

Invalid cookie header: "set-cookie: sid="";Version=1;Path=/;Max-Age=0;Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT

I am getting this exception while using apache http client jar ().
Could any please tell me what can be the cause of this exception